# How to implement optional positional parameter in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, parameters, option-type

I have a Python 2.7 script returns some data. It also takes command line positional parameters:
**filename.py -ip 172.17.12.12 -username admin**

So far I have 4 parameters have been calculated with the following function (testargv.py):

```
def getopts(argv):
    opts = {}
    while argv:
        if argv[0][0] == '-':
            opts[argv[0]] = argv[1]
            argv = argv[2:]
        else:
            argv = argv[1:]
    return opts

myargs = getopts(argv)
if '-ip' in myargs:
    ip = myargs['-ip']
elif 'username' in myargs:
    username = myargs['-username']
elif 'password' in myargs:
    password = myargs['-password']
elif 'outfile' in myargs:
    outfile = myargs['-outfile']
```

This separate .py file has been imported to the existing project (from testargv import getopts) and before executing the script the following takes place:

```
ip = getopts(argv)['-ip']
username = getopts(argv)['-username']
password = getopts(argv)['-password']
outfile = getopts(argv)['-outfile']
```

I would like to make "outfile" to be optional. So the user doesn't have to input it, the default should be
os.getcwd() + '\' + 'Select.log'

I have tried to add the following to testargv.py:

```
elif 'outfile' not in myargs:
    outfile = os.getcwd() + '\\' + 'Select.log'
```

or adding the following to the program code:

```
if getopts(argv)['-outfile']:
    outfile = getopts(argv)['-outfile']
else:
    outfile = cwd + '\\' + 'Select.log'
```

But the program without -outfile still fails: 
    **outfile = getopts(argv)['-outfile']

KeyError: '-outfile'**

Comment: The only way I can see it could be implemented now is to check in the main script length of **getopts(argv)** and if it is is not 4, set the outfile to _cwd + '\\' + 'Select.log'_, but it is not the great way, since the customer might omit another parameter. I do need to check persistence of outfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some advices:

1. try to use https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html
2. if not then:

   - do not call `getopts(argv)` many times, call it once and save result in a variable
   - consider using [`get`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method of `dict`, it returns `None` in case the key you asked for is not in the dictionary

so just change:

```
if getopts(argv)['-outfile']:
   outfile = getopts(argv)['-outfile']
else:
   outfile = cwd + '\\' + 'Select.log'
```

into:

```
outfile = getopts(argv).get('-outfile')
if not outfile:
   outfile = cwd + '\\' + 'Select.log'
```

or to:

```
outfile = getopts(argv).get('-outfile') or cwd + '\\' + 'Select.log'
```

Comment: **outfile = getopts(argv).get('-outfile') or cwd + '\\' + 'Select.log'**  this one helped! Thanks a lot